# Google Sheet - Searching within a range of cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

In Google Sheets, imagine the range A1:A10 having names of persons and the range B1:B10 having corresponding phone numbers. I have a phone number that I would like to search through range B1:B10, and if there's a match, then I would like to get the **corresponding name of the person with that phone number.**

I tried something like: `=INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(A4,B1:B10,0))`, but it returns error "Did not find value  in MATCH evaluation".

How do I do this?

**EDIT:** I've realised that the value in A4 cell is actually a number, whereas the values in range B1:B10 are all textual ones. That's probably why the MATCH evaluation fails.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/786/how-do-i-link-a-cell-in-google-spreadsheets-to-a-cell-in-another-document Look this article, it may help you. Gl.

Comment: Not really. I believe the article helps is referencing values in another Google Sheet. Are you referring to some specific answer in that article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick: `=INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(VALUE(A4),B1:B10,0))`.